# C# Unity how do we resolve/instantiate class for multi level class method calls

Tags: c#, unity-container

I am creating a project in which I need to use unity & resolve class instances, below is a sample of what my classes looks like:

```
class A
{
    public B BInstance { get; set; }

    public A()
    {
        BInstance = new B(??How do I instantiate  using unity ??);
    }

    void M3()
    {
        BInstance.M2();
    }
}

class B
{
    public C CInstance { get; set; }
    public B(C cInstance)//??How do I instantiate  using unity ??
    {
        CInstance = cInstance;
    }

    public void M2()
    {
        CInstance.M1();
    }
}

class C
{
    public D DInsatnce { get; set; }

    public C(D dInstance)//??How do I instantiate  using unity ??
    {
        DInsatnce = dInstance;
    }

    public void M1()
    {
        DInsatnce.MTest();
    }
}

class D
{
    public void MTest()
    {

    }
}
```

I don't want to call Unity Resolve under each class (A, B C, D), I can/want to call unity resolve just in ultimate parent class(A). Also I don't feel that passing instance of D, C from class A is good.

So I am looking for best way to instantiate classes C,D which then can be passed through the constructors of callers.

Many thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need here is to mark BInstance property of class A with `[Dependency]` attribute and instantiate A with `new UnityContainer().Resolve<A>()`.
Constructor parameters are instantiated by default, if they can be resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it possible to pass parameters also during run time? Like new UnityContainer().Resolve<A>(MyParamterValue)?

Comment: @Deepak, yes, you can. For instance:
`var container = new UnityContainer();`

`var c = container.Resolve<C>();`

`container.RegisterInstance(c);`

`container.Resolve<A>().M3();` // `B.CInstance` will be set to `c`.